# Ruby defaults to older version after installing newer one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I updated my ruby to 2.1 from 2.0.0p353. I used rvm update and get stable before doing rvm install 2.1. It updates but when i close the terminal it reverts back to the older version??

If it helps, I also have homebrew(my friend set it up for me). So i have no idea whats going on in my bash profile....

Thanks for the help

Comment: https://rvm.io/rubies/default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have installed a Ruby interpreter with RVM successfully you may then use it by executing the following command. Change the directory to the rails application and set the ruby version with the following commands in the terminal

`rvm use --default 2.1.0`

RVM will automatically use a ruby and gemset when you `cd` to a project directory.

**Here are few examples of selecting Ruby for work:**

```
 - rvm system                   # For system ruby, with fallback to default
 - rvm use jruby                # For current session only
 - rvm use --default 2.1.0      # For current and new sessions
 - rvm use --ruby-version rbx   # For current session and this project
```

> Refer to following **excellent** ressources for:

1. **[Examples of using RVM](https://rvm.io/workflow/examples)**
2. **[Typical RVM Project Workflow](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects)**

Comment: To set 2.1.0 as default each time the terminal is started, then the command would be `rvm use --default 2.1.0`.

Comment: This is a *explosion*... Indeed